# Strange generic method behaviour

Tags: scala, json4s

This works:

```
val rpcResponse = Serialization.read[RPCResponse[Map[String, Double]]](call("listaccounts"))
```

But this

```
val rpcResponse:RPCResponse[Map[String, Double]] = Serialization.read(call("listaccounts"))
```

gives me an exception:

```
MappingException: Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor args=
arg types=
executable=Executable(Constructor(public scala.runtime.Nothing$()))
cause=null
types comparison result=
```

Shouldn't both constructions work the same way?

EDIT:

Example case class:

```
case class AA[R](f1: String, f2: R)
```

And code:

```
val rpcResponse: AA[Map[String, Double]] = Serialization.read(
  """
    |{
    | "f1": "fff",
    | "f2": {
    |       "a":1,
    |       "b":2
    |     }
    |}
  """.stripMargin)

println(rpcResponse)
```

Comment: Please provide case class you are using for the conversion etc

Comment: @Pavel: here you go

Comment: I would assume you are using scala-json-rpc when referring to RPCResponse ?

Comment: @Pavel: No. Why you think it does matters?

Comment: well, I am trying to replicated this issue locally, can't find RPCResponse anywhere in json4s

Comment: @Pavel: It's defined in my code. You can use example which I've added after edit. This one with case class AA[R](f1:String, f2:R). Only thing specyfic for this case is usage of json4s library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157146/discussion-between-czajah-and-pavel).

Comment: feel free accept current answer

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you were required to specify default json formater.
Next code works fine for me:

```
import org.json4s.native.Serialization  
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

case class RPCResponse[R](f1:String, f2:R)

val rpcResponse:RPCResponse[Map[String, Double]] = Serialization.read[RPCResponse[Map[String, Double]]](
  """
    |{
    | "f1": "fff",
    | "f2": {
    |       "a":1,
    |       "b":2
    |     }
    |}
  """.stripMargin)

println(rpcResponse)
```

Comment: You changed:
val rpcResponse:RPCResponse[Map[String, Double]] = Serialization.read

to

val rpcResponse = Serialization.read[RPCResponse[Map[String, Double]]]
which is the very subject of the question

Comment: yeh. minor, but the second line of code also works for me!